# Dynamic Scheduler Interval C#

Tags: c#, timer

I'm writing an application that that triggers once weekly.
I set the due timer to go off Sundays at 5PM. For the interval however, how can I reset it to go off the following Sunday at 5PM?

For example if I started my application on Sunday at 4:59:50PM then the first callback will be right at the expected 5PM, however since now I need to set an interval that will be set approximately 5PM the following Sunday.

2 Techniques I'm avoiding:
1. I can manually type in (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) in order to get the interval to be a week on the timer, however due to timers being based on timer ticks and not real time I know this could potentially cause the program to fall short a few seconds each week.
2. At the end of my Callback method I can recall the Scheduler Procedure.

What I want to do is reset the interval to be approximately set for the following sunday at 5PM by recalling the code within my scheduler method after the callback is sent out.
This method may still suffer from loss time due to ticks, however since it will reset each week in code the margin of error over time will be smaller than doing a hardcoded interval and the code will be cleaner than using the practice of recalling the scheduler from the callback method.

```
  public void MyScheduler()
    {
        // trigger initial time to first day of the week (Sunday) at 5PM
        DateTime markedTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek).AddHours(17);
        //If not already sunday, increment to the next sunday
        if (DateTime.Now > markedTime)
        {
            markedTime = markedTime.AddDays(7);
        }
        // initialize callback , set start time, then set interval
        myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(sender => CallbackMethod(variables passed), null, 
            (int)(markedTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds,Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with using the windows task scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my favourite libraries is [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler). It simplifies scheduling tasks quite a bit for me. In your case I guess something like the following would work fine:

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyRegistry()
    {
        Schedule(() =>
        {
            // Do something
        }).ToRunEvery(1).Weeks().On(DayOfWeek.Sunday).At(17, 0);
    }
}
```

You can get it on Nuget

```
Install-Package FluentScheduler
```